# Trying to understand the pythonpath variable

Tags: python, shell, path, environment-variables

What is the $PYTHONPATH variable, and what's the significance in setting it?

Also, if I want to know the content of my current pythonpath, how do I find that out?

Answer (score 2):

As already answered PYTHONPATH is the search path used by python to find modules when you ''import' them.
Echoing $PYTHONPATH is only useful if you have set it.
However in python itself you can list out what it thinks it is.

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`PYTHONPATH` is the default search path for importing modules. If you use bash, you could type `echo $PYTHONPATH` to look at it.